# Синхронизация данных между основным и резервным серверами

Tags: сервер, синхронизация, балансировка

Появилась задача - настроить отказоустойчивую работу сервиса. Не очень нагруженный сервис, но зарезервировать его сетевой сервер,в рамках надежности работы - необходимо. Слышал, что в возможностях балансировщика HAProxy есть опция переключения между серверами при сбое одного из них. 
Провел тестирование такой возможности - действительно для двух virtual серверов  haproxy выполняет эту задачу. 
Но есть неоднозначность в другом вопросе, на который ответ я найти не могу пока что. Будут ли синхронизированы данные между серверами, когда активный сервер "упал", а бэкапный при этом только "поднялся"? Будут ли текущие настройки упавшего сервера переданы на бэкапный? И будут ли настройки с бэкапного,при активизации основного переданы обратно? Т.е будет ли полная синхронизация активности между серверами, если использовать для этой задачи HAProxy? 
Может быть есть другое ПО для такой задачи? Буду рад выслушать предложения.

Comment: Если кратко — не будут, все синхронизации нужно настраивать самостоятельно и **заранее**, а не когда "упал"

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос в том, можно ли это настроить с помощью  HAProxy или какого-нибудь похожего opensource ПО?

Comment: Про HAProxy не знаю, но вроде в любой «взрослой» СУБД репликация данных по разным серверам встроена прямо в них, читайте документацию к вашей СУБД

Comment: HAProxy только балансировщик нагрузки, ничем другим он не занимается. Для поддержания синхронности данных и быстрого поднятия серверов используется огромное количество различного ПО. Смотреть в сторону ПО виртуализации, облачных технологий и кластеризации. И выбор конкретного ПО будет зависеть от используемых ОС и многих нюансов вашего проекта.

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз-таки я думал, что HAProxy, это не просто балансировщик, в каком-то смысле так и есть, он выступает также switch между адресами, в зависимости от запроса клиента. Работает с cookie. Но я искал его возожность в горячее резервирование.

Comment: Буду искать что-нибудь подходящее, если актуально, то скину парочку туториалов. Если у вас есть предложения по ПО, то могу их протестировать и дать обратную связь.